# swift firebase remote notifications Not Receiving, xCode 9.0

Tags: swift, firebase, notifications

Good day everyone. First post, so I'll do my best:
I have been using stackoverflow for a while now trying to figure this out with the existing questions, with no success.

I am trying to do a simple Firebase remote push notification using xCode 9.0 beta 5. From the consol, it shows completed, but I'm not seeing any of the notifications make it to my app. I have checked the certificates, the swift capabilities, etc, and everything seems fine. Still no success. Here is may AppDelegate code. I really don't know where to go from here so any help would be appreciated.. I actually had a very simplistic version working on a released version of swift, and it doesn't work anymore either, so I believe it has something to do with the code:

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MessagingDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?
var manager = CLLocationManager()
let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Added by Ryan to support FB login:
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    // Added by Ryan to support Twitter login:
    Twitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey:"ecd84HTwPAdHMhCENbM1o2IfQ", consumerSecret:"W3HmRzYpBOMmtDpHn6J3LCdV67VVeqkz87FvqOzSSRLrvZI6Ju")

    // Set the CLLocationManager accuracy:
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    manager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    manager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
    manager.distanceFilter = USER_DISTANCE_FILTER // meters until postion updated

    // Initialize Firebase Remote Notifications:
    // Request Authorizations:
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (isGranted, err) in
        if err != nil {
            print(err!)
            return
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
    }

    // Configure Firebase:
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    connectToFMC()

    return true
}

func connectToFMC() {
    // Establish a direct connection the the FMC (Firebase Messaging Controller):
    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
}


func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

    print("Entering Background")
    self.manager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

    var geoFireActiveAgents: GeoFire!
    var geoFireActiveAgentsRef: DatabaseReference!

    geoFireActiveAgentsRef = DataService.ds.REF_ACTIVEAGENTS
    geoFireActiveAgents = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geoFireActiveAgentsRef)

    // Make a direct connection to Firebase Messaging Controller for Remote messaging:
    connectToFMC()

    // When the app comes out of sleep, we need to update the location data to the global variable and the database in case the user moved while asleep:
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {

        // log the active position to the Primary User Info:
        if let activeLocation = manager.location {
            PrimaryUserInfo.primUser.activeLocation = activeLocation
            if let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                if let userLatitude = PrimaryUserInfo.primUser.activeLocation.coordinate.latitude as Optional {
                    if let userLongitude = PrimaryUserInfo.primUser.activeLocation.coordinate.longitude as Optional {

                        // If the user is an active Agent, log his/her location in GeoFire:
                        if PrimaryUserInfo.primUser.activeAgent {

                            geoFireActiveAgents.setLocation(CLLocation(latitude: userLatitude, longitude: userLongitude), forKey: userID)

                            // Add a timestamp to see when the Agent was last active:
                            let timeStamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
                            let values = ["timestamp": timeStamp] as [String : Any]
                            DataService.ds.REF_ACTIVEAGENTS.child(userID).updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
                                if err != nil {
                                    print(err!)
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.

    print("Application Terminating")

    // Remove the active agent from the Firebase Database:
    DataService.ds.REF_ACTIVEAGENTS.child(PrimaryUserInfo.primUser.userID).removeValue()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations location: CLLocation){
    // Send background location to Firebase Database when there is a significant location change:

    self.sendBackgroundLocationToServer(location: location)
}

func sendBackgroundLocationToServer(location: CLLocation) {
    // This section updates the Firebase Database location while app is in the background.
    // It purposefuly uses a background task to 'wake up' and spit out the data.

    var bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier()

    bgTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {
        UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(bgTask)
    })

    var userLatitude = CLLocationDegrees()
    var userLongitude = CLLocationDegrees()

    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways {
        userLatitude = (manager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!
        userLongitude = (manager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!

        let geoFireActiveAgents: GeoFire!
        let geoFireActiveAgentsRef: DatabaseReference!
        geoFireActiveAgentsRef = DataService.ds.REF_ACTIVEAGENTS
        geoFireActiveAgents = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geoFireActiveAgentsRef)

        let userID = PrimaryUserInfo.primUser.userID
        geoFireActiveAgents.setLocation(CLLocation(latitude: userLatitude, longitude: userLongitude), forKey: userID)
    }

    if (bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
    {
        UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(bgTask)
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
    }
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    // New Token automatically established:
    let newToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token()
    print("newToken = \(newToken!)")
    connectToFMC()
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,  willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler   completionHandler: @escaping (_ options:   UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    // custom code to handle push while app is in the foreground
    print("Handle push from foreground\(notification.request.content.userInfo)")

    let dict = notification.request.content.userInfo["aps"] as! NSDictionary
    let d : [String : Any] = dict["alert"] as! [String : Any]
    let body : String = d["body"] as! String
    let title : String = d["title"] as! String
    print("Title:\(title) + body:\(body)")
    self.showAlertAppDelegate(title: title,message:body,buttonTitle:"ok",window:self.window!)

}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    // if you set a member variable in didReceiveRemoteNotification, you  will know if this is from closed or background
    print("Handle push from background or closed\(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")
}

func showAlertAppDelegate(title: String,message : String,buttonTitle: String,window: UIWindow){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: buttonTitle, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    window.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    if let token = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
        print("Token: \(token)")
    }
}
```

}